# HTML5 required attribute does not work

Tags: html, required

```
<form id="addsub" action="addsub.php" method="post">
  <div><input type="text" name="subname" required ></div>
  <div><input type="submit" formnovalidate /></div>
</form>
```

This is my HTML. Even though i add `required` attribute, it submits form when text is empty. What should i do?

Comment: That's probably got something to do with your `formnovalidate` setting on the very next line. ;)

Comment: but why? what wrong with formnovalidate?

Comment: It tells the browser not to validate the form. The `required` attribute is validation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `formnovalidate` attribute of the `submit` button.

More information about [formnovalidate](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp):